# Complexity of MD simulations

Tags: molecular-dynamics, complexity

I'm new to molecular dynamics (MD) simulations. What is the complexity of a molecular dynamics simulation in terms of simulation time? In other words, if I want increase the simulated time from 10 nanoseconds to 20 nanoseconds, what can I expect in terms of the increase in runtime?

Comment: If you are still interested in MD simulations, you can also check out the new-ish [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Molecular dynamics simulations are linear (`O(n)`) in the length of time simulated (assuming that the single timesteps ($\Delta t$) are unchanged).  Since each timestep is dependent only on the previous configuration (and not any of those prior to that), increasing the number of timesteps results in a linear increase in time.

Comment: Additionally, complexity in terms of simulated system _size_ typically scales with O(n^2) when not using modified electrostatics like PME.

Comment: @KeithCallenberg That is true; I didn't mention it since the question didn't ask that.  It might be more complete to say that it scales as `O(n^2)O(t)` where `n` is the size (number of particles) and `t` is the number of time steps (length of time simulated divided by the size of each time step).

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that, isn't it? It should be O(N^2) if you're studying systems without cutoffs; O(N log N) if you're doing uncharged systems with a cutoff or charged systems with mesh-based approaches.